# Bootstrap grid-system is always in front

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a fullscreen-menu. It works very good but when the page itself contains a bootstrap grid-system, the grid always is in the front. Using Google Chromes developer tools i found, it's due to all `col-*`s contain

```
position: relative
```

If I disable it in developer tools (then `position` is `static`), it's in background. 
But imho I can't just edit the whole bootstrap-css.

This is my html (removed what's too much):

```
<div class="header">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" style="display:none;" />
    <label class="toggle-btn toggle-btn__cross" for="toggle">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="info">
        test
    </label>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="menu">
            <!-- here is the menu -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="row"> 
            <!-- THIS HERE IS ALWAYS IN FRONT DUE TO POSITION:RELATIVE -->
            <div class="col-xs-6">key</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">value</div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>footer</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

the `header`-class is the whole navigation that displays or hide the `div` with class `menu`. The div hides the complete content of class `body-content` (at least it should).

So

1. is there a cause why all `col`-classes are set to `relative`? I don't want to get any bad surprises later.
2. what are the possibilities (or the correct solution) to get the grid-system in background?

Comment: Can you try adding `position: relative` to `.header`?  I have a hunch that will fix it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle this would work but only in combination with setting z-index to grater than 0. Is this the solution to do it? I'm backend-developer. no plan about front-end :D

Comment: To more directly address your concerns, the reason why bootstrap adds relative positioning to the columns is for when `col-*-offset-*` or similar classes are used.  It would make sense you would need to set the `z-index`, on `.header`, but I strongly recommend only setting it to `1`.  The fact that it needs to overlay `.body-content` necessitates the use of `z-index` to override the "painting order" of the elements.  I'll write up an answer to summarize.

Comment: Okay. I guess that answers both questions. Pls post it as an answer so I can accept it. This works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: relative` is necessary in Bootstrap for when you need to rearrange columns.  This is accomplished by using [`col-sm-push-4` or similar classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#push-and-pull).  I do not recommend overriding it as that could make your project a maintenance nightmare in the future.  It's better to use the property that was designed to override [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order): `z-index`.  Try to be careful when using this property because it tends to get abused quite a bit.

First, you only really need two rules for your case

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

`position: relative` is needed because `z-index` does not affect `position: static` elements (the default).  `z-index` only needs to be `1`.  If you find yourself needing to set it to absurdly high levels (like the 1000s) you likely just need to set the `z-index` of `.body-content`, in which case, just set it to `1` on `.body-content` and `2` on `.header`.

Either way, that should be all you need.